# Is "verifyee" a word?

Tags: meaning, nouns, is-it-a-word, neologisms

How could I correctly label the following diagram?

[image: Verification]

Comment: Even if it were a word, don't you think it sounds silly? Why do you have to use a single word anyway?

Answer (score 1):

"applicant", "respondent", "subject", "specimen", or "certificate-holder" come to mind.

The verifier doesn't verify the "verifyee", [it] checks the *state of* the "verifyee" in some manner or dimension or certification.

I can't prove it's not a valid word, but it's not a good value addition even if it were, as I don't feel it represents what you want to portray.